# How can i move files from one directory to another?

Tags: python-2.7

I am beginner in python . I want to move some files from one directory to another.
I just now i have to use some modules like Os and Shutil. and i write this code but it return an error:

```
import shutil
import os
source = os.listdir("/tmp/")
destination = "/tmp/newfolder/"
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.move(files,destination)
```

please help me

Comment: What is the error? Provide full details about it by editing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of a wild guess, but I'm pretty sure that this is your problem, so I'll give it a try.

Note that `os.listdir` returns a list of filenames only; it does not include the directory that was the parameter to `os.listdir`. I.e., you have to tell `shutils.move` where to find those files! Also, you might have to create the destination directory, if it does not yet exist. Try this:

```
import shutil, os
source = "/tmp/"
destination = "/tmp/newfolder/"
if not os.path.exists(destination):
    os.makedirs(destination)                 # only if it does not yet exist
for f in os.listdir(source):
    if f.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.move(source + f, destination) # add source dir to filename
```