# How to correctly move Files with Python

Tags: python, move, shutil

I already read some useful infos here about moving files with Python. But those are not working on my machine. I use eclipse to run python and the program should move files within windows. 
I used os.rename, shutil.move, shutil.copy and so on....

Here is my simple code.

```
import os
import shutil

source = os.listdir("C:/test/")
dest_dkfrontend = "C:/test1/"
for files in source:
    if files.startswith("Detail"):
        print('Files found ' + files)
        shutil.copy(files, dest_dkfrontend)
    else:
        print('File name not matching')
```

I receive an error like:

> ```
> with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> ```

Could you please help to address this?

Comment: does `c:\test1\` exists ?

Comment: `files` is just the _name_ of the file. Try to prepend the directory. `shutil.copy("C:/test/" + files, dest_dkfrontend)`

Comment: See this answer to a _very_ related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27151953/1639625

Comment: Post the correct indentation if you're asking for help with python.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to check if your destination directory exists or not.
and `shutil.copy` requires 1st parameter as source of file with file name and 2nd parameter as destination of file where to copy with new file name.

try this.

```
import os
import shutil

source = os.listdir("C:/test/")
dest_dkfrontend = "C:/test1/"

if not os.path.exists(dest_dkfrontend):
    os.makedirs(dest_dkfrontend)

for files in source:
    if files.startswith("Detail"):
        print('Files found ' + files)
        shutil.copy(source+files, dest_dkfrontend+files)
    else:
        print('File name not matching')
```