# Move files with python

Tags: python, jpeg, move

Continusly to [How can i move files from one directory to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151460/how-can-i-move-files-from-one-directory-to-another) i try to move all jpg files from folder r"C:\Project\layers" to folder r"C:\Project\layers\new" with this code, but i get en error:

```
import shutil, os
source = r"C:\Project\layers"
destination = r"C:\Project\layers\new"
if not os.path.exists(destination):
    os.makedirs(destination)               
for f in os.listdir(source):
    if f.endswith(".jpg"):
        shutil.move(source + f, destination)
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yaron.KAYAMOT\Desktop\python.py", line 8, in <module>
    shutil.move(source + f, destination) # add source dir to filename
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Project\\layerslogo1.jpg'
>>>
```

Comment: It’s not adding a slash between the directory name (layers) and the filename (logo1.jpg), so it's looking for a file called `layerslogo1.jpg` in the `Project` directory. You need to add the slash yourself in `source + f`, or better, use `os.path.join(source, f)`.

Comment: You should learn to read the error messages: “No such file or directory: 'C:\\Project\\layerslogo1.jpg'”. Does `C:\\Project\\layerslogo1.jpg` exist? No it doesn’t. Then your next question is why your program tries to use that path instead of the correct one `C:\\Project\\layers\logo1.jpg`.

Comment: poke,what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

You need to join the path to the file:

```
os.path.join(source,f)
```

`layers` is a directory so `...layers+filename` does not exist but `...layers\filename`does. You are concatenating the two strings, you could have use `source = r"C:\Project\layers\"` with a backslash at the end  but probably best to use join.

Comment: @newGIS, that has nothing to do with using path.join, all you have to do is replace     `shutil.move(source + f, destination)` with `shutil.move(os.path.join(source,f), destination)`

Comment: get en error :  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Project\\layerslogo1.jpg'

Comment: @newGIS, that is not possible `print(os.path.join(source,f))  ->C:\Project\layers/logo1.jpg`